# Oil constantly smoking. What is happening?

Tags: smoking

Even on an medium low temperature! And it is refined sunflower oil. It also happens with butter and other types of oil. I've been using the exact same oils and cooking on the same heat in the past and this has never happened before, but now it happens every time regardless of the type of oil or heat. And it is always a different pan. The only thing I can think of is that the stove is adding more heat than it should. What do you guys think?

Comment: What kind of stove is it and when was it last cleaned?

Comment: Electric cooktops are notorious for getting dirty (for example with splattered or spilled oil, or melted plastic) then smoking every time they are turned on, even at lower heat.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first heating the pan for the requisite time and the required heat depending on what you want to cook, *then* add the oil for only a few moments to heat it up. Then add any ingredients to the oil after its been in the pan for no more than 10-15 seconds. If you heat up a cold pan with oil in it, its much more likely for your oil to smoke since it has so much time to absorb heat.

Sometimes of course, you might want it to smoke, in which case, leave the oil in for longer.